# Explaining a Kohana redirect method

Tags: php, redirect, kohana

I have the following code in Kohana and I want to know what it actually does:

```
Request::instance()->redirect("/");
```

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 3):

First, it will get an instance of a request object (it's using the singleton pattern for tihs). It will then redirect the client to `"/"` ie. the start page. Instead of `"/"` as an argument, you can provide an url of your choice.